# Configuring Extra Public /24 Subnet with different gateway

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, netplan

I have a server where an internal adapter is configured as followed:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s4f0:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [ 199.168.96.58/29 ]
        gateway4: 199.168.96.57
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ 8.8.8.8 ]
```

However, my hosting provider gave me a extra subnet of /24 which is not using the same gateway:

```
CIDR: 199.19.124.0/24
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway address: 199.19.124.1
First usable address: 199.19.124.2
Last usable address: 199.19.124.254
Usable addresses:   253
```

I tried setting it up in several ways but I can not get the second adapter subnet to work. I can add the addresses to interface however they are not pingable from outside neither can I ping externally with the extra adapter.

This is my current netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s4f0:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [ 199.168.96.58/29 ]
        gateway4: 199.168.96.57
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ 8.8.8.8 ]
    enp3s4f1:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [ 199.19.124.0/24 ]
        gateway4: 199.19.124.1
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ 8.8.8.8 ]
```

IP Routes

```
root@s191768:/etc/netplan# ip r
default via 199.168.96.57 dev enp3s4f0 proto static 
199.168.96.56/29 dev enp3s4f0 proto kernel scope link src 199.168.96.58
```

IP added

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s4f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:a9:05:00:9e:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 199.168.96.58/29 brd 199.168.96.63 scope global enp3s4f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1aa9:5ff:fe00:9e14/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s4f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:a9:05:00:9e:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

IfConfig

```
enp3s4f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 199.168.96.58  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 199.168.96.63
        inet6 fe80::1aa9:5ff:fe00:9e14  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:a9:05:00:9e:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13923  bytes 1328243 (1.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8667  bytes 1223101 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

enp3s4f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 18:a9:05:00:9e:15  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 375  bytes 26690 (26.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 375  bytes 26690 (26.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: You cannot assign more than one gateway like that.  They have to be routed in order to have more than one gateway or you leave any other gateways out.  See:  https://gist.github.com/ThomasLeister/640812441505447ba8f19f85314fbf5b or see:  https://netplan.io/examples/  Also see:  https://netplan.io/examples/#using-multiple-addresses-with-multiple-gateways

Answer (score 0):

If your `ip a` output is relevant, then I must draw your attention to the fact, that a second adapter actually is in NO_CARRIER state, meaning it does not actually sends no receives any packets to your provider.

The problem might be either on your side (typical issues: bad/broken cable, speed negotiation failure), or on the provider side (e.g. they just forgot to UP your port at their switch, or some kind of firewall is banning the port).

What exactly your physical connection scheme is? If you do actually have two cables coming up from provider, try temporary replace second one with first, because at least first one seems to be working.

Comment: Well basically , im not sure if the Provider is actually tricking me . Because supposedly i bought this dedicated server, remote based in which he ordered an extra subnet for me which does not seem to be inside the same network tho, even the gateways are different.  He is offering me no support, but basically the first adaptor is working because it was default, what is not working is suppsoedly the addon subnet which im adding to the second adapter. I created the second adapter only to be able to set a different gateway, since if adding to the first i had no way to put the 2 gateways

Comment: well, if that server is not under your physical control, it's hard to say what's actually in there, you should consult your provider about proper connection, it's doubtful that creating second adapter on its own would work without any support from their side.

Comment: What's the purpose of separate network block you got? How do you plan to use it? Currently, you can assign it as an alias to the existing adapter, but it does not really give any benefits.

For example configuration, see "Using multiple addresses with multiple gateways" in https://netplan.io/examples/